# Tips for displaying an image in swt/jface dialog box

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm looking for tips/tutorials for displaying an image in a SWT/JFace dialog box.

Can someone please point me to the right way?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [official tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html).

If it is clickable:

```
Image image = new Image(display,
    ShellWithButtonShowingEclipseLogo.class.getResourceAsStream(
      "yourpicture"));
Button button = new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH);
button.setImage(image);
```

If it is not clickable then you can use *Label* instead of *Button*.

Comment: Acutally, the rcp app i'm working on has a link, n when clicked should display sth. like an applet with the image in it. To mimic the applet behaviour, I've got the link to display a dialog box. And i'm trying to display an image in that dialog.  after nearly 5 hr. googling, I found a tutorial about IconAndMessage dialog and tweaked the example and have accomplished it. but as i'm a complete noobie i'm in a doubt if what i did was really optimal. and would like further resources/suggestions on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understood that you are trying to display
an image in the title area of the daialog Box.

You can make use of the "setTitleImage(Image image)" function in
your main class (class which extends the Dialog )

example:

```
class DemoDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {

    public DemoDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        setTitle("Demo dialog...");
        setTitleImage(ImageObject) // Image to be displayed in your Dialog
    }

}
```